# SQL CLR created in C# cannot access local cert store

Tags: c#, encryption, sql-server-2012, cryptography, sqlclr

I cannot create SQL CLR to do a decrypt function and encrypt function from cert store with getting the resultant string from a cert.

'System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.StorePermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blahblahblahblah' failed.
System.Security.SecurityException: '

Is there a way to make SQL CLR have access to your cert stores in a sys config you can change or another trust setting?  Do I need to load the dependent System.Security.Cryptography dependent library? I ultimately want to set this up on Azure SQL Server too so that may be a roadblock as well.  I know that my decrypt and encrypt work fine when hard coding the resultant data obtained from the cert that I need for the pattern.  But the access to the cert would be better to just do:

fDecrypt('mythumbprintstringtofinditlocally', 'DLQUOUIEWLKCJLAKJA=!@#$'(some data that is encrypted with local cert)

rather than hard code the data in.  As this cert can change for environments.

```
private void SetEncryptionDirectlyFromThumbprint(string certThumbprint)
{
    var cert = GetCertificateByThumbprint(certThumbprint, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My);
}

//needs System.Security.Cryptography library.
private X509Certificate2 GetCertificateByThumbprint(string thumbprint, StoreLocation storeLocation, StoreName storeName, bool requirePrivateKey = false)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(thumbprint))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("thumbprint");
    }

    var cleanedThumbprint = thumbprint.Replace(" ", "").ToUpperInvariant();

    var store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);

    try
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var foundCerts = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, cleanedThumbprint, false);
        foreach (var cert in foundCerts)
        {
            if (!requirePrivateKey || cert.HasPrivateKey)
            {
                return cert;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        store.Close();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all it was thus far was the 'Permission level' set under Project>SQLCLR>Permission Level.  I changed it to 'External_Access' and voila, it worked right away.  Now the problem it seems will be that Azure only likes safe assemblies and just included the ability to use CLR recently.  Arghhh, cannot win them all I guess.

Comment: Correct on both counts: 1) accessing anything external to the DB requires `WITH PERMISSION_SET =  EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, and 2) SQLCLR has been introduced in the V12 Azure SQL Database, but only for `SAFE` assemblies, and only loaded using `FROM 0x01231...` and not `FROM 'path\to\file.dll'`. So no, this will not work in Azure SQL Database :-(

Comment: That is a bummer but I think I can do a partial work around that still may be secure.  Thanks for the confirmation on my assumption.